# How to list check in SQL like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

```
DECLARE @strn TABLE(Specialist varchar(MAX))

insert into @strn 
    select * 
    from dbo.fnSplitString('Skin,Medicine',',')

--select * from @strn

select * 
from dbo.StakeHolder sh 
inner join @strn ON sh.Specialist like '%'+N'@strn.Specialist'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine for table variables:

```
select * 
from dbo.StakeHolder sh 
    inner join @strn s on sh.Specialist LIke '%' + s.specialist
```